# Probability that $y-x > 0.5$ where x and y are 2 points on a line in each half

Tags: probability

Given a line interval $[0,1]$, and $M = 0.5$, $x < M$ and $y > M$. What is the probability that $x - y > 0.5$? Note that $x$ and $y$ and randomly distributed in their respective halves.

I can solve this from a graphical perspective to find the answer $\frac{1}{2}$, where I plot $y$ on the horizontal axis and $y-x$ on the vertical axis, and then I draw some lines for different $x's$, and I see that if you take all the $x$ curves, half of the curve, on average, will be below $y-x=0.5$.

What are some other approaches to looking at this problem? I feel like my method is more work than it needs to be.

Comment: By symmetry, $$P(Y-X\lt0.5)=P(Y-X\gt0.5)=\frac12$$

Comment: @PeterForeman Yes, but what did you use to determine $P(X-Y <0.5) = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Symmetry? They have the same probability and must add to $1$.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I understand now. Is the symmetry method easily adaptable to $y-x > c$ where $c \neq \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: No because then the distribution is not symmetric about $c$.